# FormatException (FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) flutter

Tags: flutter, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WY9iF.png)

I am getting this error from flutter while pulling data from flutter to sql server with net core 6 wep api please help

I searched on the internet but couldn't find anything that explains the solution.
It has been asked on this site, but the full answer has not been given or the solution has not been clearly stated. can anyone help solve this problem

Comment: Hi @Mahmut BULMUS, could you please post the output of ```print(results.body);```

Comment: Could you provide related code for use to reproduce this situation? Just based on this image is difficult to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response you are receiving does not contain JSON data; it contains HTML data. The "<" character is not recognized by the `json.decode` function, which is causing the error.

I recommend checking the headers you are sending with the request or inspecting the web backend to ensure you are receiving the correct data format.